# Compilers evaluating constant expressions

Tags: c++, optimization

I want my compiler (VS 2013) to avoid any redundant arithmetic calculations preferably by computing the following once at compiletime.

Basically I see three scenarios as below:

For example:

```
void Mesh::Draw1()
{
    const static uint32_t gStaticOffset = 0;
    const static uint32_t gVertexSize = sizeof(float) * 3;
    const static uint32_t gBoneIndexSize = sizeof(uint32_t) * MAX_BONES;
    const static uint32_t gBoneWeightSize = sizeof(float) * MAX_BONES;

    ...
}
```

vs

```
void Mesh::Draw2()
{
    const uint32_t staticOffset = 0;
    const uint32_t vertexSize = sizeof(float) * 3;
    const uint32_t boneIndexSize = sizeof(uint32_t) * MAX_BONES;
    const uint32_t boneWeightSize = sizeof(float) * MAX_BONES;

    ...
}
```

vs

```
const static uint32_t gStaticOffset = 0;
const static uint32_t gVertexSize = sizeof(float) * 3;
const static uint32_t gBoneIndexSize = sizeof(uint32_t) * MAX_BONES;
const static uint32_t gBoneWeightSize = sizeof(float) * MAX_BONES;

void Mesh::Draw3()
{
    ...  
}
```

My thoughts, please correct me if wrong:

- `Draw1()` might recompute the local expressions each function call
  depending on compiler
- `Draw2()` and `Draw3()` guarantees expression will only be computed once,
  if not in compiletime then at runtime
- Whether any of the expressions for the three variations will be
  evaluated at compile time entirely depends on the compiler

Will the compiler generate different code for each of them and if so, which one avoids the most redundant calculations?

Comment: I suggest you watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnGCDLhaxKU . Chandler explicitly notes 'const_cast' there and the implication on how const is handled -- that said, things like data flow are quite complex to predict, so best to simply test it.

Comment: @atl Sorry, I don't understand what `const_cast` has to do with anything. I guess maybe I'd understand the connection if I had time to watch the 2 hour video... Maybe you could summarize it?

Comment: See also here: http://goo.gl/GBcVKm

Comment: On a side note, you do not even have to have those static (inside functions). Any entity which can be called *a compiler* nowadays will optimize those constants.

Comment: @CodyGray Not really... there's so much going on in an optimizing compiler... and these two hours merely scratch the surface. You can even throw away all the 'const' things in your `Draw1` and it will still produce the same results.

Comment: Oh, of course. But I don't need to watch that entire video to know why. :-) The variables are initialized with constants, and it is easy for a static analyzer to determine that they are constants, regardless of whether or not you've marked it `const`.

Comment: @CodyGray Sure - but I assumed the whole point of your question was "the general case". In the general case the compiler has to proove that a value always evaluates to the same thing. In simple terms: As it turns out, you can cast away 'const', which means that in the general case it's regarded as non-const for the optimizer. In cases where you can provide proof that it's a true constant, the compiler will likely pick it up.

Comment: The other way to be sure (but not supported by VS2013) is `constexpr`: `constexpr uint32_t uint32_t gVertexSize = sizeof(float) * 3`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to be *certain* what your compiler will do unless you try it. Compile all three code examples and then look at the resulting object code.

Practically speaking, they *should* all be identical. Constant folding is about the lowest of low-hanging fruit when it comes to compiler optimizations. If your compiler isn't calculating these constants at compile-time, it is *not* an optimizing compiler. Unless you have a *very* good reason for continuing to use it, you should consign it to the garbage heap and find a different one.

Comment: I'd even use a stronger set of words - 'If your compiler isn't calculating these constants at compile-time, **throw it away** and use another one.'

Comment: @sergey I had originally written it that way, but figured it was possible that you're using a special embedded compiler that does absolutely no optimization whatsoever. Again, though, in that case you'll have to check the output to see what's happening.